# Flash Player Videos Not Loading in Ubuntu 16.04/17.04/17.10

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash, 17.10

Flash player does not seem to work properly on some sites in Ubuntu 16.04.

Try this sample link: http://www.hotstar.com/tv/silicon-valley/silicon-valley-trailer/1000186914

In Firefox, it shows "movie not loaded" and In chrome, it keeps loading but nothing happens. I have tried disabling all add-ons/extensions but still, the problem persists.

Note: It is working in earlier versions but not in 16.04 and later.

In firefox:

[image: firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in two acer laptops: Copy and paste in a terminal window:sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash